# Failed Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15 as part of Sphinx Install

Tags: mysql, centos, yum, sphinxsearch

I'm running CentOS 5.7 and trying to install Sphinx Search but keep receiving missing dependency errors.

```
$ yum install sphinx
...
Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15 is needed by package sphinx-0.9.8.1-3.el5.i386 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.15(libmysqlclient_15) is needed by package sphinx-0.9.8.1-3.el5.i386 (epel)
....
```

I have libmysqlclient.so.16 as part of MySQL / MySQL-devel.

My Question: Is there a way to have v15 and v16 of libmysqlclient.so installed on the same system and if so how would I go about it?

I've searched high and low and can't seem to find an answer; hopefully some on here can help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

install the shared-compat package,  and attempt to reinstall the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Install the remi repository:

http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en

Enterprise Linux 6 (with EPEL) i386 or x86_64

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm

rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
```

then install compat-mysql51

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install compat-mysql51
```

now install sphinx from rpm